# Posting JSON with variable using Ajax in

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was trying to put variable into JSON. I want to post it using Ajax.

**My code:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var user_Details = "1528205024";

    function checkUserForDashboard(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "api comes here",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"user_id": user_details },
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain : true,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }

    })};
</script>
```

The post request gives: `bad request error`.

Comment: I think the variable name is user_Details and not 'user_details'.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your JSON object into `JSON.stringify()` to ensure your json object is serialized in a safe string.

Also, set the content-type property.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api comes here",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({"user_id": user_details }),
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain : true,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }

})};
```

Comment: "to avoid malicious code" — That won't help you avoid malicious code at all. It will make it JSON which is what the question is asking for.

Comment: @Quentin I edited my answer. However JSON.strigify() will output string representation of a real JSON object. It will not make it JSON.

Comment: It **will** make it JSON. The object you pass to `JSON.stringify` will be JavaScript, not JSON. The only JSON you can have in a programming language is a string representation because JSON is a text-based data format. Your last comment is akin to saying "`get_name_from_database()` will output a string representation of a real human name. It will not be a name.".

Comment: @Quentin I think you might be confusing JSON.stringy() with JSON.parse()

Comment: No, I'm not. `JSON.parse` takes JSON and outputs a JavaScript object (or array, or null, or number, or whatever the top level data type of the JSON is).

Comment: @Quentin [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) also  [w3schols](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

Comment: @Ahman - They agree with me. MDN says "a JSON string" not "A string representation of JSON that is not JSON"